# Can I use numbered links in reStructuredText?

Tags: restructuredtext

Can reStructuredText do what the following Markdown does:

```
Here is some [text][1] with [links][2].

[1]: http://example.com/
[2]: http://example.org/
```

i. e. explicit binding of hyperlink text to targets with custom labels (numbers in this case)?

Comment: This reference will be useful: http://hyperpolyglot.org/lightweight-markup

Comment: @Javier As far as I can see, it does not answer the question (explicit binding of hyperlink text to targets with custom labels).

Comment: The row "link with url in footnote" is what you want.

Comment: @Javier It makes a link with the same footnote label as text. What I want is a footnote label different from the text.

Comment: Is it not exactly the same Markdown code you want to replicate in reStructuredText? Is the reference incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how I do:

```
.. _`docutils`: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/

`docutils`_ is best extensible plain text markup in the world!
```

For in-place link:

```
`Installation instructions <INSTALL.html>`_
```

For footnotes:

```
See [RFC822]_ for mail format.

.. [RFC822] http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt
```

**UPDATE**. For whose who downvote direct answer to question (this show that Markdown less capable then ReST):

```
.. _RFC822: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt

.. _alias:  RFC822_

Please read `RFC822`_.

Please read `alias`_.

Please read `RFC 822 <RFC822_>`_.

Please read `RFC 822 <alias_>`_.
```

Enjoy!

Comment: @JustSid You have a chance to change -1 to +1. I update answer ))

Comment: Here’s what I get on your last snippet with `rst2html` from Docutils 0.8.1: http://hastebin.com/kapipumute.xml

Comment: @gavenkoa That's all nice and cute, but you still don't answer the question. See the example of what the OP is asking and how non of your examples actually show something similar nor do you give a clear "yes" or "no". It doesn't matter if ReStructuredText supports more flavours of linking than Markdown if that's not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov Docutils 0.8.1 too old. Try Docutils 0.11.x

Comment: @JustSid Please, carefully look to **.. _RFC822: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt**  and **read \`CUSTOM TEXT <RFC822_>\`_** syntax in answer ))

Comment: @gavenkoa Do you even understand what the question is?

Comment: Okay, it works with Docutils 0.11, and even though it looks a bit ugly, this answers the question.

Comment: I read entry docutils docs and now deep into code. this feature isn't explicitly documented so I discover it by experimenting. But it look intuitive and don't contradict with ReST specification. I recommend ask questions in dev mail list to get response more quickly ))

Answer (score 0):

Use "anonymous hyperlinks" with [embedded references](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#embedded-uris-and-aliases):

```
Here is some `text <1_>`__ with `links <2_>`__.

.. _1: http://example.com/
.. _2: http://example.org/

More `text <holla die waldfee_>`__.

.. _holla die waldfee: http://example.io/
```